# Close questions as "Needs details or clarity"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close

Would we close questions (like https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/close/343371) if the question itself does lack information but that information has already been made available in the comments?

Answer (score 13):

*Technically*, yes, as comments are temporary and could be deleted. *Ideally*, a close reviewer could see that situation (not easy from the review queue!), and edit the clarifications into the question, flag the comments as no longer needed, then vote to leave the question open.